# Matrix input Keras

Tags: keras

I am trying to implement a neural network to detect handwritten digits. Each digit is represented by 784 digits. For technical reasons, I would like to feed this to the neural networks a 28x28 matrix.

```
import pickle
import gzip
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image as im
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Flatten, Dropout, Activation, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l2



def load_data():
    f = gzip.open("./data/mnist.pkl.gz")
    training_data, validation_data, test_data = pickle.load(f, encoding="latin1")
    return training_data, validation_data, test_data

training_data, validation_data, test_data = load_data()    


train_images = training_data[0].reshape(len(training_data[0]),28,28)
train_images_mean = np.array(train_images).mean()
train_images_std = np.array(train_images).std()
train_images = (train_images - train_images_mean)/train_images_std
train_labels = training_data[1]

validation_images = validation_data[0].reshape(len(validation_data[0]),28,28)
validation_images_mean = np.array(validation_images).mean()
validation_images_std = np.array(validation_images).std()
validation_images = (validation_images - validation_images_mean)/validation_images_std
validation_labels = validation_data[1]

test_images = test_data[0].reshape(len(test_data[0]),28,28)
test_images_mean = np.array(test_images).mean()
test_images_std = np.array(test_images).std()
test_images = (test_images - test_images_mean)/test_images_std
test_labels = test_data[1]





model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(None, 28, 28)),
    layers.Dropout(rate = 0.01),
    layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),

    layers.Dense(10, activation = 'softmax'),

])


model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='mae',
)

history = model.fit(
    train_images, train_labels,
    validation_data=(validation_images, validation_labels),
    batch_size=256,
    epochs=20,
)
```

Thank you!

Unfortunately, I cannot make sense of the error message. I have experimented with input_shape, unfortunately, nothing works except when I represent it using 784 digits (in which case input_shape = [784] does the trick).

Answer (score 0):

Normally in keras for gray scale images your input shape should be `input_shape=(28, 28, 1)` if you use Conv2D, and `input_shape = (784,)` if you use Dense. I recommend you use Conv2D for better performance.

Here is a simple example of MNIST classification in keras:
https://keras.io/examples/vision/mnist_convnet/